# Layer to Consume SOAP Web Service in Spring MVC

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc, soap

We have Spring MVC application with layers controller, service, dao and more. We also have SOAP Web Services. I'm struggling with which layer the app should consume the SOAP service. Is it in the controller (maybe create a separate method and call it from controller method)? or is it in the service layer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service layer  , you should have abstraction over the soap instead of calling the soap client directly from service layer so if soap client changes also you dont need to change service layer.

Comment: Yes. We do have abstraction over the soap. Thank you.